# How to get width of C# Form?

Tags: c#

I'm making a text editor, and it will have the ability to be resized. However when it is resized the close button along with a few other buttons at the top are kinda stuck in the middle. I would like to do something like this.

Ex.

```
 private void Size_Change(object sender, EventArgs e) // Event after maximize or restore
    {
        Close_Button.Location = Width - (width of button);
    }
```

what is a method of doing getting the width of a form and then subtracting from that width?

Comment: You should anchor them properly. See the buttons properties and set the correct anchors. No need to manually calculate the position.

Comment: Are you using Winforms? Gtk-Sharp? or any other framework? Let's assume, it is Winforms from Visual Studio. Go to designer and set the 'Anchor' property of the button to 'Left' (disable 'Right' option).

Comment: My bad, the sides (left/right should be reversed _(in previous comment)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use anchor points on the button. Like Sani Singh Huttunen said. It's located in the properties of the button.

That way it will be resized or relocated with the form

Comment: Anchor is absolutely the way to do it, but if you do want the Widt of the button its' Close_Button.Width.  Every Control has a .Width property.

Answer (score 0):

you need change "Location" to "Left" property:

```
private void Size_Change(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Close_Button.Left = this.Width - Close_Button.Width;
    }
```

or create new Point to Location property.